# legacy code matlab/simulink

Tags: matlab, legacy-code, simulink

What is the meaning of legacy-code in Matlab/Simulink? In the context of using s-function, c code?

Comment: Are you referring to the [Legacy Code Tool](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/legacy_code.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "legacy code", they mean code written before the Simulink model for another purpose and then without using the S-function API. The Legacy Code Tool generate for you the S-function code calling you own old code.

Comment: but this paart od code "legacy code" is used in the model ? do you mean : I have c code I put it in a s-function ?

Comment: Yes, it's not modified, just called. You should try by yourself the example in http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/sfg/bq4g1es-1.html

Comment: clement, I asked te question because I want to find bugs on generated C code from the model , I have a simulink model "written in .m" that I want to convert to C and check it with a bug finder tool, so I generate a s-function from model1 then add my own s-function.

Comment: Let's assume the bug is in your model and not in the generation. It's probably easier to debug in Simulink ou pure Matlab than in C.
Test yout .m directly in Matlab line by line or by displaying values.

Comment: I want to check to generated code before implement it in embedded system.

Comment: so I can have in a same mode, an s-function generated by right click ->generate s-function from subsystem and my own c code inplemented in s-function ?

Comment: the purpose is to be able to check c code of all model before implemet it in microcontroller

Comment: It's hard to say for sure without the code but it's probably feasible. Do you have a simulator of your µC ? Is this intermediate check necessary ? Maybe a validation of the Matlab model and tests on the hardware are enough, aren't they ?

Answer (score 1):

The Legacy code is like a Handwritten Code for any application. You convert that Legacy code to a System Function( S-Function) so as to convert a Legacy Code to a Model. The conversion of existing Legacy Code to a Matlab Simulink Module is referred as Reverse Engineering.

The S-function not only helps in modeling the function but also in Testing the application as matlab provides a very good testing support.